# Mule ESB Uber connector in Mule ESB I am getting a message like" Base Uri is not matched with redirect Uri "

Tags: javascript, java, mule

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00N3Y.jpg)

https://www.mulesoft.com/webinars/saas/building-powerful-connector-scratch

This is link which is provided by mulesoft and I just followed this video and I created uber connector is successfully and installed in my anypoint studio. It is successfully deployed while hitting this flow browser redirects login page of Uber after completion of login it was showing "Base redirect Uri does not match the requested redirect ". can any one try this video please help me out where i have done wrong and please provide link to get those uber API Credentials

Answer (score 0):

Just cross check with the base uri in the Raml file with the url it is trying to hit. it might be one of the reason. Make sure you are hitting perfect url.